# Table permissions with table created with an 'altered schema'

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I have a 12c oracle database. I have an admin user called CIDBADMIN.
I use this user to log in to the database and install objects etc. into the SAMPLE_SCHEMA.

The following code:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;
SET SERVEROUTPUT on;
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=SAMPLE_SCHEMA;

create table TESTTBL ("some_field" VARCHAR2(1024) NOT NULL);

grant all on TESTTBL to CIDBADMIN;
```

Gives the error:

```
Error starting at line : 7 in command -
grant all on TESTTBL to CIDBADMIN
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01929: no privileges to GRANT
01929. 00000 -  "no privileges to GRANT"
*Cause:    "ALL" was specified but the user doesn't have any privileges
           with the grant option.
*Action:   Don't grant privileges on that object.
Commit
```

I am not sure how I should correct this. I have checked the documentation and google and can't work out what I can do to correct this.
I want a solution that doesn't require me to log in to the database as the SAMPLE_SCHEMA user.

Edit 001: 
I have worked out that if I log in as CIDBADMIN with as sysdba role I am able to execute the grant. This solves my problem but I would like to know which exact permission I have to grant to CIDBADMIN to allow it to do this and eliminate the need to log on as sysdba.

Comment: Which roles and privileges does your 'admin' user already have?

Comment: Though you have changed the schema the user has not changed . Meaning you are creating table in `sample_schema` `cidbadmin` user. And you may not grant/revoke privileges to/from yourself. So after creating the object you have to connect as `sample_schama` then can grant the object privileges to `cidbadmin` user.

Comment: Alex, I can grant the admin user any privilege I need to. I have already granted it a huge amount. I just need to know which it needs for this. Jaapkota, i don't want my ci machine to need access to all the passwords for all schemas so connecting as sample_schema isn't a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specificed which roles and privileges you've already granted, but if the `create table` is working then you presumably must have at least done:

```
DBA> grant create any table to CIDBADMIN;
```

then you see the behaviour you've shown:

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=SAMPLE_SCHEMA;

Session altered.

SQL> create table TESTTBL ("some_field" VARCHAR2(1024) NOT NULL);

Table created.

SQL> grant all on TESTTBL to CIDBADMIN;
grant all on TESTTBL to CIDBADMIN
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01929: no privileges to GRANT
```

If you grant the `grant any object privileges` privilege to your admin user:

```
DBA> grant grant any object privilege to CIDBADMIN;
```

... you can attempt your original table grant step too, but what you've shown gets a different error:

```
SQL> grant all on TESTTBL to CIDBADMIN;
grant all on TESTTBL to CIDBADMIN
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01749: you may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from yourself
```

As far as I'm aware there isn't a way around that, unless - as you've discovered - you give your user DBA privileges and connect `as sysdba`.

You mentioned that you are trying to avoid needing to know the password for the `SAMPLE_SCHEMA` account - otherwise you could just connect as the schema owner directly and create whatever needs to be in that schema. You can do that with [proxy authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/authentication.htm#GUID-8A9DCA8A-0294-47D8-81B2-61A3BF4817B6):

```
DBA> alter user SAMPLE_SCHEMA grant connect through CIDBADMIN;
```

Then you can connect into that schema, using CIDBADMIN's password, and run the commands without needing to set `current_schema`:

```
SQL> connect CIDBADMIN[SAMPLE_SCHEMA]/cidbadmin_passwd;
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "SAMPLE_SCHEMA"
SQL> create table TESTTBL ("some_field" VARCHAR2(1024) NOT NULL);

Table created.

SQL> grant all on TESTTBL to CIDBADMIN;

Grant succeeded.
```

You can use proxy authentication from SQL*Plus, or over JDBC (including from SQL Developer).

And when you connect back as your admin user again you can see the table:

```
SQL> connect CIDBADMIN/cidbadmin_passwd;
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "CIDBADMIN"
SQL> select owner from all_tables where table_name = 'TESTTBL';

OWNER
------------------------------
SAMPLE_SCHEMA

SQL> select * from SAMPLE_SCHEMA.TESTTBL;

no rows selected
```

With this mechanism you don't need to give your CIDBADMIN user any of the powerful (and therefore dangerous) privileges you're currently having to employ to create objects. The individual schema owners do need the necessary privileges to create their own objects (e.g. `create table`) though.

Answer (score 0):

May be [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598597/using-an-oracle-pl-sql-stored-procedure-to-grant-rights-on-another-users-tables) from [mustaccio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1227152/mustaccio) help you...

Comment: Link-only answers are not really approved of, even to other questions on this site. If the issue was actually the same then this question could be flagged/closed as a duplicate. But it isn't the same; that answer is about role in dynamic SQL, which isn't being used in this question.